# any better way to avoid the nested for loop/for each?

Tags: javascript

any better way to avoid the nested for loop/ for each in this example ?
I am working on this function that will populated those divs from a nested array the array structure is a copy from a data base file it is really nested is there any solution without changing the incoming arr structure ?
I just want to completely avoid the nested loop.

```js
let [...divMulti] = document.querySelectorAll('.insert')
 
let Incoming = [{ day: [{ el: '1' }, { el: '2' }, { el: '3' }] }, { day: [{ el: '1' }] }, { day: [{ el: '1' }] }]
        let data1 = Incoming.map(element => {
            return element.day
        })
        for (let i = 0; i < divMulti.length; i++) {
            data1[i].forEach(el => {
                let item = `<div>Element${i}</div>`
                divMulti[i].querySelector('.here').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', item)
            })
        }
```

```html
<div class='insert' >parentDiv
<div class='here'></div>
</div>


<div class='insert' >parentDiv
<div class='here'></div>
</div>

<div class='insert' >parentDiv
<div class='here'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you looking for? a better performance, better quality in the code? I don't think your question is clear.

Comment: better speed in this case. the problem is I want to avoid the nested loop at all cause.